# Add a percentage to the grand total in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

In Woocommerce I am using [Woocommerce One Page Checkout](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-one-page-checkout/) plugin and I would like to add 10% GST on the Grand Total.

Here is an example (without 10% GST on the Grand Total):

```
Cart Total: $200
Delivery charges: $20
Grand Total: $220
```

The result should look (with 10% GST on the Grand Total):

```
Cart Total: $200
Delivery charges: $20
Grand Total: $242 (including 10% of cart total + 10% on Delivery)
```

On Products listing page, here is what I did to show total like I want:

```
$woocommerce->cart->total = $woocommerce->cart->total + number_format(($woocommerce->cart->total * 10) /100, 2);
```

> **The problem is that when I place an order, I have a grand total of `$220` instead of `$242`on the payment page.**

How can I update the order total here?
Is there any way that we can a 10% GST on the total cart amount in Woocommerce?

**Note:** I tried to debug it using Network calls and found that Woocommerce is sending cart array that includes all the products with a total and order page might be calculating the total again excluding GST I applied using above code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will add 10% to the grand total:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_cart_grand_total', 20, 2 );
function custom_cart_grand_total( $total, $cart ) {
    return $total * 1.10;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.